# IntelliJ IDEA shortcut to switch 2 words

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a shortut (or a way to define one) in IntelliJ to switch 2 words?
Eg. 
    `final static`
Shortcut to switch to `static final`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it under "Code" menu : <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd>

Comment: The best answer! This is what I was looking for. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

Under the "Edit" menu look for the "String Manipulation" flyout and there should be an entry called "Swap Characters/Selections/Lines/Tokens".

Selecting both words and then using this command will present you with a dialog. Typing space into the dialog and hitting return will swap two words.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> will get you a shortcut to this command if you type "swap" after its dialog comes up.

---

If the same pattern of words occurs multiple times it would be more effective to perform a replace with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

Comment: I don't have the menu "String Manipulation" under "Edit". My IJ version 2018.1.5

Comment: Ah, that feature comes from the "string manipulation" plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If your only issue is `final static` (and other) modifiers order, you can enable `Missorted Modifiers` inspection: `Preferences` | `Editor` | `Inspections`.

After that all missorted modifiers will be automatically highlighted, and you'll be able to fix it simply by either hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> or doing `Cleanup Code` (also available to do via hotkey).

Comment: Thanks for this highlight. It was only an example